# Nested try/except statement for method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder if it is possible to handle the exceptions raised when calling a method via a function (this is necessary as in the production code different objects are created depending on args passed) as in the following example.

Function `createObj` triggers the creation of an object `Obj_A` based off different criteria and is supposed to handle any exceptions that may occur with `Obj_A`.

```
def createObj():
    try:
        return Obj_A()                
    except:
        print("Bad boy!")
```

`Obj_A` has a method that creates a nested object, in which I would like to catch exceptions and handle those at the level of `createObj`:

```
class Obj_A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def myFunc(self, var):
        return self.Obj_B(self, var)

    class Obj_B(object):
        def __init__(my, self, var):
            try:
                1/0
            except:
                raise ValueError("Don't divide by zero")
```

Calling `createObj` works just fine. But calling `createObj.myFunc('var')` raises the `ValueError("Don't divide by zero")`.

Of course, handling the error on a

```
try:
    createObj().myFunc('var')
except:
    print("Not what I need")
```

would work, but is unfortunately not desirable for this use case.

Is there a way to handle this exception on the `createObj` level and return `Bad boy!`?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the use case a little better. Creating a function that wraps all functions inside the class is not too hard but is usually a weird solution.

Comment: I'm more thinking about a proxy object with getattr and callable check

Comment: I dont understand your use case.  when you call `myFunc(var)` you've already done, and succeeded - `createObj()` - (you forgot your parenthesis).  You can't go back in time and oh, 2 operations ago, something should have happened.  Unless you group it as a *single call*, intercept the div/0 error and decide to return BadBoy instead - which is totally doable, just doesn't look like what you are doing - which is exposing the created instance first, then calling method.  This question needs quite a bit more clarity.  Also *class method* has a specific meaning in Python, just say *method* instead.

Comment: The use case is to load multiple data sets in object A (raw data) and then specify the subset of data (cleaned data) a user is exposed and can interact with in object B. We had to change how data was stored on file and the easiest way to maintain legacy support was to define two classes for `Obj_A` based on the storage option. Depending on the storage option some processing had to be either done in the `Obj_A __init__()` method or in the one for `Obj_B`, requiring two separate classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to handle an exception with the `except` clause that will be raised in the future after the corresponding `try` statement. It's impossible, and unnatural if it's possible.

Instead, do in other way like this example.

```
def createObj():
    def handle_exception(e):
        print("Bad boy!")
    return Obj_A(handle_exception)

class Obj_A(object):
    def __init__(self, handle_exception):
        self.handle_exception = handle_exception

    def myFunc(self, var):
        try:
            return self.Obj_B(self, var)
        except Exception as e:
            self.handle_exception(e)
```